# How to yank text from a kill-ing and instert it at the cursor location in another terminal window?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, clipboard

How to copy, if it is possible at all, a text from one terminal and paste/input it into another without selecting it?

More precisely, within the same terminal window, I can kill the text line by `CTRL-U` and then yank the killed line by `CTRL-Y`. However, `CTRL-Y` doesn't seem to work when trying within another terminal window or even to another terminal tab.

I'm using bash 5.1.16, Konosle terminal in a KDE desktop environment (plasma 5.27.6) in Arch Linux x86_64.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/751514/4667

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/751514/108618).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kill / Yank features don't use a system clipboard, instead this is a feature of the shell... If you're set on using `^U` and `^Y`, then you need to integrate with the system clipboard (e.g: using `xclip`).

This example uses <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>Y</kbd>, source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088763/1347519

```
_xdiscard() {
    echo -n "${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}" | xclip
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
    READLINE_POINT=0
}
_xkill() {
    echo -n "${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}" | xclip
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}"
}
_xyank() {
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}$(xclip -o)${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
}
bind -m emacs -x '"\eu": _xdiscard'
bind -m emacs -x '"\ek": _xkill'
bind -m emacs -x '"\ey": _xyank'
```

---

You can also get similar functionality if you were to use `tmux` or `screen`.